# java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError org/sonar/batch/bootstrapper/EnvironmentInformation

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube

sonarQube9.0.1 CE（Java 11 ） + pgsql （docker install） 。 my project is Java 8
when i excute mvn sonar:sonar，my project failed

```
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm = plugin>org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:3.9.0.2155
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/D:/project/repository/org/sonarsource/scanner/maven/sonar-maven-plugin/3.9.0.2155/sonar-maven-plugin-3.9.0.2155.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/D:/project/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.4/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.4.jar
```

by the way, sonarqube9 needs java 11 means my project also needs java 11?

Comment: You can use Java 11 compiler to produce Java 8 code. The configuration could be set on the maven-compiler-plugin. From Java 9 the "release" configuration option is useful: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#release

Comment: You should not use the org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin. You have to use `org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.9.0.2155` that works correctly..

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java 11 compiler to produce Java 8 code. The configuration could be set on the maven-compiler-plugin, you can see an example below:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <release>${jdk.console.version}</release>
                <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Where ${jdk.console.version} would be 1.8 in case you want compile to be executed in a JRE 8